# Error thrown by SSIS package : The input Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file is not valid

Tags: ssis, wsdl

Im trying to connect to a web service using Web Service task. I have used the WsdlFile property to dynamically set the path of WSDL file.

The package executes fine on my local system. When I try to execute the same package on my TEST server ( via Active Batch scheduler), it fails with the following exception :
-1073548540,0x,An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: The input Web Services Description Language (WSDL) file is not valid.

I have placed the WSDL file in my TEST server location ( which is equal to the path set in WsdlFile property) and also have Delay Validation = True on WebService task in the package.

Kindly help on how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, was there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this will only occur if the WSDL file is invalid (obviously!) or the SSIS package can't find the WSDL file. Ensure that your configuration exposes the WsdlFile property.

To do so, select SSIS > Package Configurations, and create or edit an existing configuration. Tick the WsdlFile property to expose it:

[image: WsdlFile property]

This will add a property to a configuration file. Ensure that the value of that is set to a full file path e.g. "D:\SSIS\WebService.wsdl"

[image: Config file]

Finally, once deployed, ensure that your SSIS package references the configuration file you've created.